# Promoting an answer to a question?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

So, I'm a bit annoyed today... you see, I got over 100 reputation today for answering a question.

Why am I annoyed? Because it is for the almost obvious answer I supplied to the [river flowing out of an ocean](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69917/is-it-possible-for-an-ocean-to-have-a-river-flowing-from-it-into-a-lake/69920#69920) question. I'm glad people liked that answer. BUT... I really hoped people would notice the answer that I finally managed to put together for the highly intriguing "[can you hack a computer with an arrow?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69300/designing-hacking-arrows)" question.

Because, you see, when the question was first posted, I put up a good answer (I thought; community seemed to agree) about how it could be accomplished. But I felt... empty. Like the question lingered on the edge of possible. So I pulled some resources at work and, lo, I think it really is feasible with some very specific hardware (which is within the scope of the question!).

Unfortunately, people have already read that question, and they don't seem likely to go back to it later. So after watching it go a full day without being noticed, I decided to write this meta purely for the humble brag of promoting a damn cool answer because, well, maybe someone will actually go ahead and make the movie the question inspires! So [here's my updated answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/69893/26246)!

Comment: I think people simply skip looking at established questions that have an accepted answer and only scroll down a certain distance before moving onto another question.  Your newer answer is currently at rank #16.

Comment: I totally get your feeling. But thats the price you gotta pay for answering older question

Comment: My comment to Molborg applies here too. I think we've all been in this situation. Chew the carpet, kick the cat, that down, move on into the sunshine. There's always tomorrow,

Answer (score 2):

woohoou, new game, stories sharing :)

I have spent 4 or 5 full days on an answer (I mean literally, 32-40 hours dedicated to writing the answer - fact checking, testing, calculating, bad English fixing etc) actually the story repeated itself twice, so I have 2 beloved answers, really brilliants of wisdom from all of my 100 answers, the beauty of the beauty.

I will not promote them here, of just make promotion for no reason.

They have to be useful for people who needs the information, they are not just for free internet points, which we might help each other without problems, and which you might get for the reason of writing a question on meta showing that you care and u are in some pain because of your art was undervalued. As result of that people will give you the attention you wish, because they are good people and would make you a favor for basically nothing. But will it fulfill you?

I post links to those answers times to times, when I think they are related to the topic and relevant in discussions. So far, I got +2 votes on each, and more or less, I guess they were from people who probably really were interested in the answers them self, not in the help me to feel better ;)

Comment: You have my deepest sympathies. For a long time my highest rated was something I dashed off in five minutes. Answers I felt a justified pride in, because, IMHO, they were good answers hardly rated. There's no accounting for taste. There are a couple of old questions I want to go back and answer in the hope I can contribute something good. Forget the points! I'm not here for the numbers. On the positive side I've started getting a slow trickle of upvotes for older answers to my surprise. perhaps, eventually, getting the love they deserve. I hope yours do too.

Comment: @a4android, my top rated answer is still a 5min job, and I can't see myself displacing it any time soon. Sometimes you catch the zeitgeist and sometimes something you really care about and write up carefully just doesn't get the attention you feel it deserves.

Comment: @Separatrix I have feelings of amusement and bemusement, even though I know crowd approval is a fickle beast. I expected many others would be in the same boat. There are old Qs I want to answer & will do so because that feels right. No other reason is necessary.

Comment: @Separatrix There is nothing bad in 5-minute answers, a good answer is a good answer. The answer can be good as an idea, or it can be detailed or it can be both. Shorter the answer is, easier and faster is it to read one, and more likely it will be read. More details are in the answer more points of possible disagreement with the answer. I usually upvote the answers when they do contain a good point and do not contain too much "wrong" details. And I do not care how much one have spent the time in writing, and no one should.

Comment: Have read the work of no-name guy from the internet, a detailed one(I bet he spent a quite some time, I'm just seeing him growing the idea for month's), about a possible implementation of a thermonuclear engine, I'm so glad he did it, it was written as if it was for me. The short or long answer, the way you form it, you just choose who you address - broader audience or targeted audience or not an audience but individuals. Btw @a4android thanks for sympathies and edit

Comment: Always glad to help. We all have feelings and wouldn't be human without them. I like your attitude. Give the best answer you can and if those interested in the subject find it then good. It's what I try to do too. You have to have a standard and this works for me. Here's to more good answers from us all!